# Does Game DVR continue running when you unsnap it?

Tags: xbox-one

If I, say, wanted to record my previous 5 minutes gameplay, using "End clip now", and unsnapped Game DVR as it was saving the footage, would it still save that footage?

Comment: My wording is a bit off, I think. If anyone can make it sound better, feel free.

Comment: why dont you try it?

Comment: My guess is that you would have corrupted data and it wouldn't be able to watch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will (mostly). If you are recording as you're playing a game, the recording will continue in the background. If you are recording something that has already happened, then a proportionately small amount of time will be "Shaved Off".